# The condition pattern is not supported: -l convert .htaccess to web.config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

I use import for convert htaccess to web.config on iis but i get message 'The condition pattern is not supported: -l.' where -l is RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l in htaccess,

htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Output

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <!--# Necessary to prevent problems when using a controller named "index" and having a root index.php-->
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <!--The condition pattern is not supported: -l.-->
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

how to make the -l is supported in web.config, because if not use the -l i can open my website and get error "404 - File or directory not found."

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Picking up from the [`RewriteCond` directive's](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_rewrite#rewritecond) documentation:

> ## `-l`
>
> Is symbolic link.
>
> Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it
>   exists, and is a symbolic link. May also use the bash convention of `-L`
>   or `-h` if there's a possibility of confusion such as when using the `-lt`
>   or `-le` tests.

Since, in Windows, there is no concept of a symbolic link, you would not need this condition. It is already being covered by the other two conditions you have specified:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
```